# Protractor .isPresent() stop the loop

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

I am trying to loop clicking the dropdown selection until one element is present.Even though console log the "found data" the loop is not stop.

```
while (i < 23) {
//select dropdown selection
 let selectDeviceid = lists.get(i);
 deviceLogsPage.selectDevice();
    //click on the first dropdown
    selectDeviceid.click();
    //click apply button
    deviceLogsPage.clickApply();
let bool = deviceContent.isPresent().then(function (isDisplayed) {
      if (isDisplayed) {
        console.log("found data");
        return true;
        //found and stop the loop
      } else {
        console.log("no data");
        return false;
      }
    });
    console.log(bool);

    if (bool === true) {
      break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: since you're working with asynchronous code and promises ... `bool` will be a **Promise** ... never true or false, always a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're working with asynchronous code and promises ... `bool` will be a **Promise** ... never true or false, always a promise

You can use async/await

it doesn't HAVE to be in a Async IIFE - if this code is already in a function, just make that function `async`

```
(async() => {
    while (i < 23) {
        let selectDeviceid = lists.get(i);
        deviceLogsPage.selectDevice();
        selectDeviceid.click();
        deviceLogsPage.clickApply();
        let bool = await deviceContent.isPresent();
        if (bool) {
            console.log("found data");
            break;
        } else {
            console.log("no data");
        }
        i++;
    }
)();
```

Answer (score 0):

shorter way is to make bool a part of while condition

```
let bool;
while (i < 23 && !bool) {
  let selectDeviceid = lists.get(i);
  deviceLogsPage.selectDevice();
  selectDeviceid.click();
  deviceLogsPage.clickApply();
  bool = await deviceContent.isPresent();
  i++;
}
```